# How can I fix this UV issue?

Tags: modeling

This is the continuation of my question 'How can I fix this SubSurf Modifier issue?':I don't understand why the UV don't follow the smooth surface of the sphere while all the corners and edges have a crease of 1 as I apply a Subsurf Modifier. Thanks.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: what kind of UV unwrap have you made? You might want to "mark seams" where your edges are sharper. While in edit mode, select the sharp edges, press space, write mark seams, after you are done, select all,  press U adn select just Unwrap. This technic is more time consuming but you will have more control on your UVmap, besides, you will have a more organized UVmap.

Comment: @MCunha I didn't explain this issue very well. I didn't aplly any UV, I am just wondering why the render is not smooth around the corner and if i won't get any issue with the UV/materials in the next step?